# A connection about different coordinate system

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Assume $f$ is a smooth function, $(\phi, U)$ and $(\psi,U)$ are two coordinate  system, $\phi(p)=\left(x_1(p),\ldots,x_n(p)\right)$, $\psi(p)=\left(y_1(p),\ldots, y_n(p)\right)$ and
$$ y_i(p)=x_i(p)-x_i(m), $$
where $m\in U$ is a fix point.

I need to proof $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(m)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(m),$$

where $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(m)=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right|_m f=\frac{\partial f\circ \phi^{-1}}{\partial u_i}(\phi(m))$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i}(m)=\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i}\right|_m f=\frac{\partial f\circ \psi^{-1}}{\partial u_i}(\psi(m))$ and $u_i\circ(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=x_i$.

The $\phi^{-1}$ and $\psi^{-1}$, I do not know how to deal with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I get into how to formalize this, notice that what's going on here is that $\phi$ and $\psi$ differ by a translation, whose differential in matrix form is the identity matrix, so this really follows by the chain rule.

To write it out in coordinates, notice from the definition that if $T_z$ represents translation by fixed $z=(z_1,\cdots z_n)$, then

$$\frac{\partial u_j\circ T_z}{\partial u_i} = \frac{\partial (u_j+z_j)}{\partial u_i}=\delta^j_i\text{.}$$

Moreover, you have

\begin{align*}
\psi(p) &= \phi(p)-\phi(m) =(T_{-\phi(m)}\circ \phi)(p)\\
\psi & = T_{-\phi(m)}\circ \phi\\
\psi^{-1} &= \phi^{-1}\circ T_{-\phi(m)}^{-1} =  \phi^{-1}\circ T_{\phi(m)}\\
f\circ \psi^{-1} &= f\circ \phi^{-1}\circ T_{\phi(m)}\text{.}
\end{align*}

And finally observe $\psi(m)=0$.

So now you can just use the chain rule in its coordinate form.

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f\circ\psi^{-1}}{\partial u_i}(\psi(m)) &=\frac{\partial f\circ\phi^{-1}\circ T_{\phi(m)}}{\partial u_i}(0) \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f\circ\phi^{-1}}{\partial u_j}(T_{\phi(m)}(0))\cdot \frac{\partial u_j\circ T_{\phi(m)}}{\partial u_i}(0)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial f\circ\phi^{-1}}{\partial u_j}(\phi(m))\cdot \delta^j_i \\
&=\frac{\partial f\circ\phi^{-1}}{\partial u_i}(\phi(m))\text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: A very clear proof, thank you very much.